# Access VBA taking forever to start running Excel VBA after switch to Azure Virtual Desktop

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have the following code that is being run in Access VBA to open a macro enabled excel document. Before a migration to Azure virtual Desktop everything works fine (still works fine when using the old platform) but after the migration it hangs when attempting to run the Excel macro.

Putting break points into the Access and excel macro I can see that access hangs when attempting to run my sub "Main" and excel is sitting there waiting for the next instuction.

When I open the excel and run this sub manually everything works fine, only when I call it from Access does it hang. Anybody got experience with something similar?

```
Public Sub DFImportData()

set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Open ("\\LOCATION\TO\NETWORK\SHARE\Data_Freshness.xlsm")
xl.visible = True
xl.Run "Main"
xl.ActiveWorkbook.Save
xl.quit
Set xl = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: The new platform may interpret this as dangerous behavior and block it - from one office application opening another office file with macros and running a macro in there.

Comment: that would make sense if it stops it completely but it does allow it after ~10 minutes